# Not able to link Glew with Cmake

Tags: c++, opengl, build, cmake, glew

I am getting into OpenGL with c++ using VScode on OS X. I have installed glfw and glew with brew. I have succesfully build glfw library with cmake and I can open a window, but when I try to build glew it always gives me an error.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
project (test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_executable(test
src/main.cpp
)

add_subdirectory(glfw)

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

if (GLEW_FOUND)
    include_directories(glew/include)
endif()

if (APPLE)
    target_link_libraries(test ${GLEW_LIBRARY})
    target_link_libraries(test "-framework GLUT")
    target_link_libraries(test "-framework OpenGL")
endif()

target_link_libraries(test glfw ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

It gives me this error when I try to 'make' it:

```
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"_glewInit", referenced from: _main in main.cpp.o.
```

Comment: Do you use glew in static or dynamic library? If you use a static library, then you've to set the preprocessor definition `GLEW_STATIC`.

Comment: I am trying to build it from source. I downloaded zip file from glew's website and unpacked it into my project directory.

Comment: You could try manually linking GLEW instead of using `find_package` for a quick and dirty fix.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to include GLEW with

`brew install glew` (This step builds glew and installs it on your system, so are you saying that this is failing? Otherwise, there is no further building of glew required.)

And then in my top level CMakeLists.txt

`find_package(GLEW 2.0 REQUIRED)`

And in the CMakeLists.txt that setup my target for my main.cpp that needed to `#include "GL/glew.h"` I added the line:

`target_link_libraries(${MAIN} GLEW::GLEW)`

${MAIN} being a variable I set for my main target name.

Comment: THANKS! I've been searching the whole internet for three hours but no one mentioned `GLEW::GLEW`! Where is one supposed to find such information? any official doc?